# What does 'lew' stand for in 'lew2' or 'lew4'?

Tags: character-encoding

I'm seeing the term 'lew2' and 'lew4' being used in reference to character size in certain files.  I know that the number represents how many bytes are used to store certain types of characters (maybe wide chars?), but I'm not sure what the 'lew' part stands for.  My best guess is 'length of wide'.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be Little Endian Word 2 Bytes (or 4 Bytes), as opposed to Big Endian.

Comment: I've heard a few different sources hazard this guess.